# How could i change domain name in ubuntu?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, subdomain

I got 2 domains but whenever i open one of those domain, the output is my laravel project. I only want one domain in accessing the project. How could I achieve that? Im using ubuntu server in my domains. Or if possible i want to redirect the second url to the first url whenever who visits it. Thanks.

PS: There is no `ect/hostname` in my server and i dont know why

Domains

http://digi.propnex.net = This is the only domain that I want

https://payment.propnex.net = This one has HTTPS and I want the other one to have this https

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Hi, Please provide how you've setup webserver. Are you using Apache Or Nginx?

If you don't know how to setup a hostname using apache, This tutorial might help you. [How to setup apache hosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: its apache sir @ShreyanshPanchal